# Host HTTP WCF Service in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, http

I'm hosting a HTTP WCFService in a Windows Service, in local network it works perfectly, but if the client is in another network and try to connect with de public IP doesn't work.

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config              
  file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for         
  libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFService.ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"     
          contract="WCFService.ServiceContract">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/WCFService/service/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: probably the firewall?

Comment: You are showing web.config of server part. Show web.config of client.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505126/how-to-set-up-my-wcf-service-to-be-able-to-be-accessed-by-remote-clients

Comment: Firewall disabled. If i access in the Server browser to http://localhost:80/WCFService/service/ it works, but if I put the public IP not.

Answer (score 1):

The service metadata publishes *http://**localhost:80**/WCFService/service/* to the client. This URL is not accessible from outside the local host.

In order to access the service from another network using a public IP the service metadata should publish *http://**PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS**/WCFService/service/* to the client. This can be done dynamically depending on the URL used by the client. Just add *useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress* to service behaviors.

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="...">
         ...
         <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
       </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

See [Auto-resolving a hostname in WCF Metadata Publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564029/auto-resolving-a-hostname-in-wcf-metadata-publishing).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you give a config like this:

```
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/WCFService/service/" />
```

It would be listening in the loopback address due to the usage of **locahost**. Change this to the actual public IP address (i.e., not 127.0.0.1) or Server name and check again.